# Sound stops if laptop charger unplugged on a Lenovo G570

Tags: sound

The sounds stops immediately if I unplug the laptop charger and nothing will make it produce sound again even with my own sound devices connected to the laptop!
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a G570 Lenovo.

Comment: also,happens frequently, all videos and Flv's on the internet (like youtube and others) get really fast that I can't watch or even listen to anything !

Comment: Please edit this comment into your question.

Comment: what does lspci -vvv, or lshw output? Mine works. Look in BIOS settings, as it can have crazy power save settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a drivers' problem, so be sure of install them. If you didn't install any drivers/your soundcard's drivers yet, you can follow the next steps:

- Click on the **Dash**
- Search for **Additional** and click **Additional Drivers**
- Wait a bit, and you'll see a list with all the compatible drivers for your computer. You can install your graphics card drivers (I usually install the post-release drivers) and all your other devices.
- Check if your soundcard name appears at that list, select the entry for it and click Activate. After a while, you'll have to restart your computer.

After restarting, it should be working OK if it was a driver-related problem. I hope it works to you and tell us soon!